# Is dask dataframe processing speed linearly increased with the numbers of workers?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

Hi I'm new to dask dataframe and looking at how well it can improve the processing time with distributed computing. My code is working with a 5m+ row file as below

```
client = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')

start_time = time.time()
print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(start_time)))

ddf = dask.dataframe.read_csv(filename)
ddf = ddf[['Prod_desc']].drop_duplicates()
ddf = ddf.query(filter_text)

df = ddf.head(1000, npartitions=-1)

end_time = time.time()
print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(end_time)))
print(end_time - start_time, 'secs')
```

The results are below

distributed 1 server, 1 worker/server
22.344669342041016 secs

distributed 2 server, 1 worker/server
11.367061614990234 secs

distributed 3 server, 1 worker/server
9.111485004425049 secs

distributed 3 server, 2 workers/server
6.44242000579834 secs

distributed 3 server, 3 workers/server
8.706154823303223 secs

The processing speed didn't improve linearly as we expected. When we used 3 workers per server, more time was used than 2 workers per server.

Anybody has an idea how this happened? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I read the code correctly, you read the data, then drop duplicates and later show the top 1000.
I suspect that one or both of these steps require a shuffle of the data, perhaps even to one place.

If you need to shuffle that costs time (Data transport between nodes will touch both network and disk between servers, not sure what happens within a server), so that would be my primary suspect for why you see a slowdown.

In general parallel processing should speed things up linearly, but this especially holds if you can do many steps of processing and the shuffling is just a minor component, in this job the processing is so light that it is possibly even taking less time than simply transporting the data.

Answer (score 0):

could you pls try to remove

```
ddf = ddf[['Prod_desc']].drop_duplicates()
```

and test the time again?
This step might drop too many lines so too few lines for the next step.